# Can two light beams polarized at 90 degrees be filtered out with the same filter?

Tags: visible-light, polarization

I'm especially thinking about 3D cinema. The two frames are projected with different polarization hence they can be separated by the 3D glasses. But all this does not make sense if the angle difference is 90 degrees, does it? The cross section of the two light waves will both look like: +

So am I right that when we want to use polarization to carry information, we have to avoid the multiples of 90 degrees?

Comment: There is [circular polarization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarized_3D_system#Circularly_polarized_glasses).

Comment: Can you draw a diagram?